# How to pause an appmaker deployment?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'd like to pause a deployment while I do some offline data maintenance. However, I have found no way to do so.

I can temporarily revoke all access rights from the deployment, but it's a bit of a crutch. Is there a switch somewhere that I overlooked ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in_maintenance and when it is true, nothing is done in the app.

Comment: Sure, one could do that.  That would however mean to throw around code in a lot of places, at least in every page. In this case, it's just easier to revoke all access and re-add it after maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put `loader.suspendLoad();` in your App startup script, and if anyone tries to access the file, it'll just spin on the loading screen indefinitely.

Comment: Doesn't seem that feasible, since that would require the deployment to be republished every time. Looking through the GCP documentation it also does not appear that there is a solution to temporarily suspend a project and to display a message that the site is under maintenance or something similar.

Comment: Actually, re-publishing twice for maintenance is doable, but not easier than just revoking access to everyone temporarily.

Seconding that the temporary suspension with a nice maintenance message really would be ideal. I'm just stumped that this doesn't exist because it seems like such an obvious need.

Comment: @MrPrinter If you don't mind publishing twice for maintenance purposes, then you could still use the loader.suspendLoad() method but then call app.showPage('MyMaintenanceMessagePage') and then resume the loader. However, that would still load everything in the background, even if your maintenance page did not have any links to any of the other pages, so I don't know if that would work for you in regards to the integrity of your maintenance project.